# What are the critical points of this multivariable function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

What are the critical points of the function $z=x^3+y^3 -12yx$? I had $(0,0)$ and $(4,4)$ as the only ones, but saw other answers in the class. Also, are the values maxes or mins, as I had $(0,0)$ was a saddle and $(4,4)$ was a min, but again heard that the answer was different. Lastly and somewhat off topic where is a guide to how to use LaTex so my equations look better for the future on this sight?

Comment: Just [type it into W|A](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x^3%2By^3-12+x+y+stationary+points)...

Comment: Also, when you edit the question so that its meaning is changed, it might be nice to notify those who already answered the old question.

Comment: I upvoted the answers to the earlier version, as they are correct for that question. Thanks to Hans for drawing attention to the substantial change. Tokola, your answers to the current version of the question look fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

we have the system
$x-6y=0$
$y-6x=0$
solving this we get
$x=0,y=0$

Answer (score 1):

$$\nabla f=\begin{pmatrix}2x-12y\\2y-12x\end{pmatrix}=0 \implies (x,y)=(0,0)$$

In this problem, $(0,0)$ is a saddle point. You can prove this by showing that $$\det H\left.\right|_{(x,y)=(0,0)}<0$$

Answer (score 0):

Giving pointers for the cubic version.

We have $\partial z/\partial x= 3x^2-12y$ and $\partial z/\partial y=3y^2-12x$. So at a critical point $x^2=4y$ and $y^2=4x$. Squaring the first equation implies that
$$
x^4=16y^2=16(4x)=64x,
$$
so $x(x^3-64)=0$. This implies that $x=0$ or $x=4$. By $x\leftrightarrow y$ symmetry also $y=0$ or $y=4$. Checking the above partial derivatives again reveals that we can only pair up $x=0$ with $y=0$ and $x=4$ with $y=4$. This leaves us with the critical
points $P_1=(0,0)$ and $P_2=(4,4)$.

The Hessian is
$$
H(x,y)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}z_{xx}&z_{xy}\\z_{xy}&z_{yy}\end{array}\right)=
\left(\begin{array}{cc}6x&-12\\-12&6y\end{array}\right).
$$
You should have learned how to use the Hessian to determine the nature of the critical points, so I leave that to you.

But there's something familiar about this function. You may have seen it before in the context of [Folium of Descartes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folium_of_Descartes). It is one of the book examples for doing implicit differentiation and/or using parametric presentation of plane curves.

Here's the image of the plane curve consisting of solutions of $z=0$.

[image: Folium]

The curve passes thru the origin, so $z(P_1)=0$. Given that the folium intersects itself at $P_1$ it is not at all surprising that in any neighborhood of $P_1$ the function $z(x,y)$ will have both positive and negative values. A closer examination reveals that in the four regions of the plane having the folium as boundary and meeting at the origin the sign of $z(x,y)$ alternates $+-+-$ (by continuity the sign can only change at the zero locus). This hopefully gives you a mental image of a typical saddle point. Use the Hessian to verify that $P_1$ is, indeed, a saddle point.

OTOH $P_2$ is inside the loop. By visual inspection the loop and its boundary form a compact set $K$. By continuity the function thus attains a largest and smallest value in $K$. At the border we have $z(x,y)=0$, and in the interior, say at $(x,y)=(2,2)$, we have $z(2,2)=8+8-48<0$. So $z$ is negative inside the loop. This implies that $z$ must attain a minimal value in the interior of the loop, so there is no alternative to concluding that $P_2$ is a local minimum. Again, verify this using the Hessian.